# "Swap not available" - I must manually "swapon" after every reboot

Tags: swap

I am on Ubuntu 12.04, Thinkpad Edge 13, encrypted home. A message in the System Monitor tells me that swap is "not available". I can get it back using the `swapon` option in gparted (I thought I could also do `sudo swapon -a` in a terminal, but that does not work). The problem is that I have to `swapon` after every reboot. How can I switch it back on so it stays on even after a reboot?

my fstab:

```
# # <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> 
proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0 
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation 
UUID=47641b93-9d12-4e6a-b803-dde28f0e5725 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=47641b93-9d12-4e6a-b803-dde28f0e5725 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

Comment: You realise the two UUIDs you posted above are actually different? There's a "-8" missing after the "4aa8" block in the swapon response (and I suppose in fstab as well).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have no configuration for swap in `/etc/fstab`. Add following line to that file:

```
UUID=<uuid> none   swap    sw    0       0
```

**You have to replace `<uuid>` with the `uuid` of your swap partition**. To do that, run `sudo blkid`

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="88A0D0A1A0D09752" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="0620D9F920D9EFA3" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="c282b418-2045-4852-8789-88a44360a0bb" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="f99c6a0c-790a-45ca-a1a9-8874f5a2999b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="4cc2e909-ebd1-4c72-abee-aa32035bf330" TYPE="swap"
```

This is a list of my partitions, and as you see, **/dev/sda7** is my swap partition. So you can copy the value of UUID corresponding to your swap, omitting the quotes, and use it for your fstab file.

Comment: And what if among the rows returned by `sudo blkid` there isn't one with 'TYPE="swap"'?

Comment: @niconic you'll need to create swap partition

Answer (score 3):

After the upgrade to 12.04, certain little anomalies occurred. I was unaware my swap partition wasn't working until I tried to open a large file in Gimp.

`blkid` shows:

```
/dev/sdb6: UUID="3e0550cf-4a55-4aa8-80fa-24103c1b25a7" TYPE="swap"
```

but it is not active according to System Monitor. The UUID was definitely right but no go ... not sure how I got to this command:

```
blkid -p /dev/mapper/foo-swap_1
error: /dev/mapper/foo-swap_1: No such file or directory
```

File manager showed me a 0 byte icon, filename control, -- so what was supposed to be written there? By what?

```
sudo swapon --all --verbose yielded
swapon: cannot find the device for UUID=3e0550cf-4a55-4aa80fa-24103c1b25a7
```

I edited the `/etc/fstab` file adding

```
/dev/sdb6   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Reboot and System Monitor shows it active.

This was the first site I found for help; in my case, the UUID did not work even though it was in fstab, so there is something missing 'in the middle'. This may help someone, who knows.