# After restarting, swap becomes 0 gb

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted, swap

I used a live USB to increase the size allocated to Ubuntu. Now I am on my OS. I increased the swap from 8 GB to 11 GB, but now I can't see it is used.

```
$ sudo lsblk              
[sudo] password for caner: 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   7.5G  0 part /media/caner/UBUNTU 16_0
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0 222.3G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0    11G  0 part 
└─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi

$ free -m          
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7834        5452         245          80        2136        1949

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           784M  9.4M  775M   2% /run
/dev/sda2       219G   25G  183G  13% /
tmpfs           3.9G   30M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M   13M  499M   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs           784M   60K  784M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       7.5G  1.6G  6.0G  21% /media/caner/UBUNTU 16_0

$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="32F0-543D" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="16b2efe3-e142-4d6e-bc0a-22fc9dff9d73"
/dev/sda2: UUID="a18cf8e7-12f8-40df-9e3b-2f0605c6f661" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ffeeec5b-943a-4d86-9836-e1be818b1669"
/dev/sda3: UUID="9c1fc3a8-ef4a-451a-9e8f-7f07dc18db8d" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="linux-swap" PARTUUID="848d50d8-c99d-45c6-83db-d8268eef3871"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UBUNTU 16_0" UUID="ECC1-9477" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="001c3909-01"

$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a18cf8e7-12f8-40df-9e3b-2f0605c6f661 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=32F0-543D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=f4bb47fb-7475-44ba-9e20-b8f931b22c9b none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=32F0-543D  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
```

I don't want to do anything because I broke my previous system recently so I don't want to do it again.

While on the system, if I use GParted and click my 11GB area for "swap on" and after I close GParted I see swap is 11 GB:

```
$ top                                                                                                                                                 ✭ ✈ ✱
top - 13:52:43 up 4 min,  2 users,  load average: 4.80, 3.19, 1.29
Tasks: 287 total,   1 running, 227 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 41.7 us,  3.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 54.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8022928 total,   220828 free,  5531752 used,  2270348 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 11534332 total, 11534332 free,        0 used.  2061940 avail Mem
```

But if I restart it goes and And it takes a lot of time to open Ubuntu.

What can I do?

Comment: I did this and now it seems work https://askubuntu.com/questions/194775/swap-not-available-i-must-manually-swapon-after-every-reboot but still it takes long time.

Comment: If i hibernate and wake up, it starts a new ubuntu. Not brings mine hibernated.

Comment: Please also provide the output of "sudo blkid". This will reveal if UUID in fstab is correct or not.

Comment: I stand corrected: you already did. Yes, there is a mismatch.

Comment: What about hibernate problem?

Comment: Your current question was: AFter restarting, swap becomes 0 gb. If this has been solved, then please close this question. You can then open another. I do not see reference to 'hibernate problem' in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Your swap partition is not being used because it is not correctly announced in your configuration file `/etc/fstab`. Your swap file is `/dev/sda3` with UUID "9c1fc3a8-ef4a-451a-9e8f-7f07dc18db8d". The reference to it in your fstab file is broken, because it still lists the `UUID` before the change.

To solve the issue, edit your `fstab` file. I provide instructions that may or may not be too detailed for you depending on your experience.

1. Open your `/etc/fstab` configuration file as root for editing:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```
2. In the line for swap, replace the existing `UUID` by the correct one, i.e., the one provided by the `sudo blkid` command.
   Replace:

   ```
   UUID=f4bb47fb-7475-44ba-9e20-b8f931b22c9b none    swap    sw     0       0
   ```

   by

   ```
   UUID=9c1fc3a8-ef4a-451a-9e8f-7f07dc18db8d none   swap    sw     0       0
   ```

   (only the UUID number is being changed here.
3. Save the file and exit. Press Ctrl+S (this saves) then Ctrl+X (this exits nano)

You can quickly check if all is good without rebooting:

```
sudo mount -a
```

This re-executes the fstab file. There shouldbe no output from this command. Any output indicates an error. If there is no output, verify whether your swap is active

```
free -m
```

or

```
swapon -s
```