# After resizing the swap, takes too long opening and hibernate problem

Tags: hibernate

I tried to increase swap size.

and then had those problems

[AFter restarting, swap becomes 0 gb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073610/after-restarting-swap-becomes-0-gb)

but solved the temporary swap size problem.

Normally it took 3 seconds to open laptop but now it takes 1-2 minutes to open. It started after that resizing.

I dont know what i broke. I can post output of anything if you need.

```
% free -h                                                                                                                                                                                           
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        6.0G        945M        118M        731M        1.2G
Swap:           10G        1.9G        9.1G
```

Comment: Run `free -h` and add to your post!

Comment: The answer you received to your previous question looks pretty correct and should have solved your problem.

Comment: I solved my problem in the prevous question. It only made swap area permanent. It did not affect boot time. I added free -h to question @GeorgeUdosen any help