# After resizing the swap, it takes too long time to open laptop

Tags: 16.04

I tried to increase swap size.

and then had those problems

[After restarting, swap becomes 0 gb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073610/after-restarting-swap-becomes-0-gb)

but solved the temporary swap size problem.

Normally it took 3 seconds to open laptop but now it takes 1-2 minutes to open. It started after that resizing.

I dont know what i broke. I can post output of anything if you need.

```
% free -h                                                                                                                                                                                           
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        6.0G        945M        118M        731M        1.2G
Swap:           10G        1.9G        9.1G
```

And when i hibernate and wake up, black screen comes

Comment: It would be interesting to indicate in that other question how you solved the problem. Was the answer there adequate or did you solve in another way? The idea is that you may find help here, but you should also share back to the site, and in particular to other users that may have a similar issue.

Comment: I wrote as comment. https://askubuntu.com/questions/194775/swap-not-available-i-must-manually-swapon-after-every-reboot i did this. Also someone posted simlar solution.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I missed the command. You swapon suggests that at least the swap is fine. Also the size is fine. Note however that hibernate does not work well in linux on many hardware. Can you see if the startup problem persists if you startup and fully shut down a few times in a row? Next, check whether the problem is still there after you disable swap in fstab (put comment sign # in front of the line).

Comment: @vanadium i restarted lots of times. Now it is better but before it was 3-4 sconds. now 6-7 seconds but it is ok. Now only hibernate is probllem. maybe i should remove it totally

Comment: That is better and shows it may have had to do with some initialisation of swap during startup. Indeed, unfortunatelly, usually the recommendation is to disable hibernation in case it does not work reliably. Sleep, where the computer is put in a very low power mode, but all is kept in memory, works better on more hardware.

Comment: @vanadium i also use sleep always, but for example while travelling if a damage comes, it can be bad for hdd because it is working.

Comment: Not sure if HD is working in sleep mode. Makes no sense and would consume quite some power.